# Node client not able to communicate with Python socket.io server

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, flask, socket.io

I have a python socket.io server setup along.
It can communicate with python socket.io client but not with equivalent javascript client.

Version Info:

- socketio     0.2.1 (python)
- socket.io-client@4.6.2 (node)
- socket.io@4.6.2 (node)

*Python socket.io server:*

```
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Client connected:', sid)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('Client disconnected:', sid)

@sio.on('message')
def handle_message(sid, data):
    print('Received message:', data)
    sio.emit('response', {'message': 'Server received your message'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

*Node socket.io client (could not connect):*

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to server');
    socket.emit('message', 'Hello from Node.js client');
});

socket.on('response', (data) => {
    console.log('Received response:', data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected from server');
});
```

*Python socket.io client (connects):*

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Connected to server')
    sio.emit('message', 'Hello from Python client')

@sio.event
def response(data):
    print('Received response:', data)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from server')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
    sio.wait()
```

I have also tried using flask, flask_socketio but still same problem.

However the Node's server can communicate with Python based clients.